# Google-Adwords PHP HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-ads-api

So I will begin with a small introduction, I am a student worker for my university that works with a small tech team. I am currently helping them with a website that they are building and the main person working on the site is not necessarily a programmer. So I am helping him by contributing what little I know. (I am a junior in college, I am ok with C++)

So here is the issue we are having currently. We have a form that is on our landing page of our site, it is handled and made by a third party. What we want to be able to do is to track every time that the form is submitted successfully so we can use it in our AD-Words campaign (which I believe we can do from the server-side). We are using HTML, PHP and JavaScript. My question is this:

- A.) Would it be possible to pass a value from the server into a value that went into an if statement that would allow a Google Ad-Word conversion.
- B.) We have multiple courses and so it would be preferable if we could do this with the most minimum amount of coding (possibly dynamic variables with dynamic names..?)

I hope the description has been thorough with this question, if it is not possible then that isn't a big deal. I just wanted to be able to help make this process a bit more efficient and concrete. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to ascertain how useful a specific adword is in directing users to your site? Or are you just trying to see how many users of your site are interested in a specific course?

Comment: Well, what I believe we are doing is looking for a conversion rate while using AD words. So, what we are looking for is say someone fills out the form we have on our site. It gets sent to our server saying complete or whatever it may say and we get a verification. We want to be able to track those "conversions" in some way and I figured this would be the easiest without using an onclick type javascript event that would give us some false positives. (Such as they filled out the form wrong and had to resend it).

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention is that we have some... 20+ courses I believe that we want to track the conversions for, I hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Doesnt help much I'm afraid, I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve, if you are already using google adwords, it will show you the conversion rate of people who visit your site, and then proceed to a success page. If you need to track this based on the course, just make the course part of the URL string, i.e. www.site.com/success/course1 then your adwords campaign will show you a conversion tree (i.e. how many people who viewed page X also viewed page success/course1)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it probably wouldn't make much sense... But I appreciate the advice, and honestly I don't know if we thought about it that way.. Thanks a lot though for your responses!

Comment: Are you trying to just keep a count of those conversions?  Or do you want to do something with those conversions?  A good question to ask your team is, what is the **point** of tracking conversions?  What do they want to do with them once they've got them?  If it is just so they have a number then fine - use Google Analytics.  But if they want to use those conversions in a marketing campaign with AdWords then that is something different and there are other techniques :-)

Comment: We are getting together to talk about a solution for this today, I am probably just more confused about it and am explaining the issue very oddly... :( Thanks for the response though! I appreciate it.